# How do I check if the a block is indirectly connected to another specific block in Minecraft

Tags: java, minecraft

I am working on a mod for Minecraft which will allow the user to create large moving structures similar to the way that RedPower did. Source available [here](https://github.com/Cethric/Stuff-MincraftForgeMod/tree/master/src/main)
I am using forge 1.8-11.14.1.1357, an I am trying to check if a block is connected to the controller block either by another block or directly to it. My current method however raises a StackOverflow error due to the recursion getting to deep. How can I go about simplifying the code so that recursion can be avoided if possible.

```
public boolean isAttachedToController(BlockPos pos, World world) {
        IBlockState state;
        boolean up;
        state = world.getBlockState(pos.up());
        if (state.getBlock().getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("cethric.stuff.block.BlockMovingController")) {
            up = true;
        } else {
            if (Arrays.asList(Stuff.getConfig().get("allowed_blocks", "Blocks", new String[]{}).getStringList()).contains(state.getBlock().getClass().getCanonicalName())) {
                up = isAttachedToController(pos.up(), world);
            } else {
                up = false;
            }
        }
        boolean down;
        state = world.getBlockState(pos.down());
        if (state.getBlock().getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("cethric.stuff.block.BlockMovingController")) {
            down = true;
        } else {
            if (! state.getBlock().getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("net.minecraft.block.BlockAir")) {
                down = isAttachedToController(pos.down(), world);
            } else {
                down = false;
            }
        }
        boolean north;
        state = world.getBlockState(pos.north());
        if (state.getBlock().getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("cethric.stuff.block.BlockMovingController")) {
            north = true;
        } else {
            if (! state.getBlock().getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("net.minecraft.block.BlockAir")) {
                north = isAttachedToController(pos.north(), world);
            } else {
                north = false;
            }
        }
        boolean south;
        state = world.getBlockState(pos.south());
        if (state.getBlock().getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("cethric.stuff.block.BlockMovingController")) {
            south = true;
        } else {
            if (! state.getBlock().getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("net.minecraft.block.BlockAir")) {
                south = isAttachedToController(pos.south(), world);
            } else {
                south = false;
            }
        }
        boolean east;
        state = world.getBlockState(pos.east());
        if (state.getBlock().getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("cethric.stuff.block.BlockMovingController")) {
            east = true;
        } else {
            if (! state.getBlock().getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("net.minecraft.block.BlockAir")) {
                east = isAttachedToController(pos.up(), world);
            } else {
                east = false;
            }
        }
        boolean west;
        state = world.getBlockState(pos.west());
        if (state.getBlock().getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("cethric.stuff.block.BlockMovingController")) {
            west = true;
        } else {
            if (! state.getBlock().getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("net.minecraft.block.BlockAir")) {
                west = isAttachedToController(pos.west(), world);
            } else {
                west = false;
            }
        }
        return up || down || north || south || east || west;
    }
```

Stacktrace is available as a GitHub Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/Cethric/362f801aeea36a877750)
BlockMovingController.java source [here](https://github.com/Cethric/Stuff-MincraftForgeMod/blob/master/src/main/java/cethric/stuff/block/BlockMovingController.java)

Comment: Please show us the exception stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your Method is not terminating.

```
up = isAttachedToController(pos.up(), world);
```

This line is your problem: it will basicly go up infinitly, because the first block doesn't have an controler up to it, then asks the upper block. This one has a controler on top neither, but instead of terminating, it will ask the block above again.

Take a look in the code below. Calling it with the parameter `checkNextBlock = true` should fix the problem.

```
public boolean isAttachedToController(BlockPos pos, World world, boolean checkNextBlock) {
    IBlockState state;
    // check the block above
    state = world.getBlockState(pos.up());
    if (state.getBlock().getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("cethric.stuff.block.BlockMovingController")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if(checkNextBlock)
            if (Arrays.asList(Stuff.getConfig().get("allowed_blocks", "Blocks", new String[]{}).getStringList()).contains(state.getBlock().getClass().getCanonicalName())) {
                if(isAttachedToController(pos.up(), world, false))
                    return true;
            }
    }
    // check the block below
    state = world.getBlockState(pos.down());
    if (state.getBlock().getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("cethric.stuff.block.BlockMovingController")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if(checkNextBlock)
            if (! state.getBlock().getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("net.minecraft.block.BlockAir")) {
                if(isAttachedToController(pos.down(), world, false))
                    return true;
            }
    }
    // check the nothen block
    state = world.getBlockState(pos.north());
    if (state.getBlock().getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("cethric.stuff.block.BlockMovingController")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if(checkNextBlock)
            if (! state.getBlock().getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("net.minecraft.block.BlockAir")) {
                if(isAttachedToController(pos.north(), world, false))
                    return true;
            }
    }
    // check the southen block
    state = world.getBlockState(pos.south());
    if (state.getBlock().getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("cethric.stuff.block.BlockMovingController")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if(checkNextBlock)
            if (! state.getBlock().getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("net.minecraft.block.BlockAir")) {
                if(isAttachedToController(pos.south(), world, false))
                    return true;
            }
    }
    // check the eastern block
    state = world.getBlockState(pos.east());
    if (state.getBlock().getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("cethric.stuff.block.BlockMovingController")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if(checkNextBlock)
            if (! state.getBlock().getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("net.minecraft.block.BlockAir")) {
                if(isAttachedToController(pos.up(), world, false))
                    return true;
            }
    }
    // Check the western block
    state = world.getBlockState(pos.west());
    if (state.getBlock().getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("cethric.stuff.block.BlockMovingController")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if(checkNextBlock)
            if (! state.getBlock().getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("net.minecraft.block.BlockAir")) {
                if(isAttachedToController(pos.west(), world, false))
                    return true;
            }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, however doesn't this then only search 1 block around the caller. For instance if the controller block was 20 blocks away but still "connected" via a line of blocks then would it still be found?  This is what i ended up with [here](https://gist.github.com/Cethric/86ed1d4639cc422b29c8) and [here](https://gist.github.com/Cethric/8376c29cd5d2f06f12ad)

Comment: You could replace the boolen with a int and decrease it every iteration. Your problem is that you cant scan EVERY block.

Comment: How often is this method called, because i think it will slow down very much. Specaly because i guess it will scan only the block above and get a stackoverflow while doing this

Comment: I will change the code to impliment that, and i don't wont to be scanning every block. The current search is set to a 64x64x64 cube.  It is currently quite taxing, although it is no where near as bad as what I had it at before I was doing a basic scan of weather the block was actually connected and not just surrounded by air.